# How to write a Serialize instance for this GADT?

Tags: haskell, ghc, gadt

Below is a module that attempts to implement a `Serialize` instance for a simple GADT.  Unfortunately the `get` implementation for the `Reorder` constructor complains that there is no `Ixed a` constraint.  Is there any way, beautiful or ugly, to implement this?  I can't add `Ixed a` to the instance context because the `Update` constructor needs to work for values that don't satisfy this constraint.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

import Control.Lens (Index, Ixed)
import Data.Serialize

-- | Two different ways of updating a value - replacing it completely or,
-- if it is an instance of Ixed, re-ordering it.
data Op a where
  Update :: Serialize a => a -> Op a
  Reorder :: (Ixed a, Serialize (Index a)) => [Index a] -> Op a

instance Serialize a => Serialize (Op a) where
  put (Update a) = putWord8 1 >> put a
  put (Reorder ks) = putWord8 2 >> put ks
  get = do
    i <- getWord8
    case i of
      1 -> Update <$> get
      2 -> Reorder <$> get
      _ -> error "instance Serialize (Op a) - corrupt data"
```

---

Addendum: One simplification to this might be to make the type variable `a` a phantom type, so that `Op` looks like this:

```
data Op a where
  Update :: Serialize a => ByteString -> Op a
  Reorder :: (Ixed a, Serialize (Index a)) => [ByteString] -> Op a
```

The type could then be used to properly decode the byte strings. Not sure whether this helps

Comment: I realize `Ixed` does not imply a total ordering of elements, my real instance has additional constraints.

Comment: I assume `Op a` is going to be part of some larger recursive structure, and you want to serialize `BiggerThing a` containing lots of `Op a`s at types `a` both with and without `Ixed a`, right?

Comment: This looks tricky to handle. Ideally, we should somehow serialize the `Ixed` dictionary together with the data, but that might be very hard and result in a very inefficient, very redundant serialization format. As a partial fix, one might add to that instance a custom class constraint such as `class IsIxed a where isIxed :: Maybe (Dict (Ixed a))`, and then populate this class with "enough" types, covering "enough" cases to make the serialization useful. Or, perhaps, even `Typeable a` so that we can handle a small number of "known good" cases. Not an ideal solution.

Comment: K. A. Buhr - Yes, I need to serialize larger structures containing these.

Comment: I'm not seeing that making `Op` a GADT is helping. Why not two different datatypes `Update, Reorder` with two different instances of `Serialize`?

Comment: I will consider this approach.

Comment: I don't see how to use separate types for `Update` and `Reorder` because I need to put these `Op`s into a container, serialize, store, and retrieve them.

Answer (score 3):

What you're trying to do is impossible in general.  Essentially, you're trying to get GHC to deduce `Ixed a` and `Serialize (Index a)` given only `Serialize a`.  Granted, this may work for any use case you have in mind, but it doesn't *generally* work, which is why GHC is rejecting your instance.

I said "impossible in general" because if you specify the types you care about, then it's definitely possible.  This means you'll have to list out all the types you have that can be serialized from `Reorder`, but that's really as good as you're going to get.

There are multiple ways to do this, but I think the simplest way is to use the `constraints` package to capture what you want in a `Dict`.  You'd start by defining:

```hs
class MaybeSerializeIndexed a where
  canSerializeIndex :: Maybe (Dict (Ixed a, Serialize (Index a)))
  default canSerializeIndex :: (Ixed a, Serialize (Index a)) -> Maybe (Dict (Ixed a, Serialize (Index a)))
  canSerializeIndex = Just Dict
```

The default signature (which requires the `DefaultSignatures` pragma) is key to making your life simple as it means that you can list out the types you care about with easy one liners, as in:

```hs
instance Serialize a => MaybeSerializeIndexed [a]
instance Serialize k => MaybeSerializeIndexed (Map k a)
```

Beyond that, you can make an overlapping instance to deal with the types that *don't* work with `Reorder`:

```hs
instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} MaybeSerializeIndexed a where
  canSerializeIndex = Nothing
```

With this machinery in place, you can write your instance:

```hs
instance (MaybeSerializeIndexed a, Serialize a) => Serialize (Op a) where
  put (Update a) = putWord8 1 >> put a
  put (Reorder ks) = putWord8 2 >> put ks
  get = do
    i <- getWord8
    case (i, canSerializeIndex @a) of
      (1, _)         -> Update <$> get
      (2, Just Dict) -> Reorder <$> get
      _ -> error "instance Serialize (Op a) - corrupt data"
```

Note that adding the `MaybeSerializeIndexed a` constraint to your instance is really not a big deal because there is an instance for *every type*.  This also means that if you add a new type to your system without adding an `MaybeSerializeIndexed` instance for it, then you won't get a type error when you try to deserialize it—you'll only get a runtime error.  For example, if you add a new type `Foo` where you know `Ixed Foo` and `Serialize (Index Foo)` but you don't add `instance MaybeSerializeIndexed Foo`, then you won't get a type error if you write a program that tries to `get` a `Foo` value, but you will get a runtime error when you run it.

Answer (score 2):

As per @AntC's comment, it might be worth rethinking why you need `Op` as a GADT.  However, here's one approach that seems to work...

It's kind of fundamental to Haskell that you can *demand* an instance `Ixed a` but not act conditionally depending on whether or not an instance `Ixed a` exists.  So, one way or another, you're going to have to explicitly enumerate all the types `a` you want to use in this serialization and manually indicate which ones will and will not be treated as `Ixed`.

Once you've resigned yourself to that, there's a glaringly obvious solution.  If you want to support `Op a` for `a ~ Int` (not `Ixed`) and `a ~ [Int]` (with `Ixed`), you can define two instances:

```
instance Serialize (Op Int) where
  put (Update a) = putWord8 1 >> put a
  put (Reorder ks) = putWord8 2 >> put ks
  get = do
    i <- getWord8
    case i of
      1 -> Update <$> get
      _ -> error "instance Serialize (Op a) - corrupt data"

instance Serialize (Op [Int]) where
  put (Update a) = putWord8 1 >> put a
  put (Reorder ks) = putWord8 2 >> put ks
  get = do
    i <- getWord8
    case i of
      1 -> Update <$> get
      2 -> Reorder <$> get
      _ -> error "instance Serialize (Op a) - corrupt data"
```

and the main problem is solved.  The remaining problem is how to make this boilerplate palatable.

Here's one way.  We can define a type class to provide a `getOp :: Op a` operation, equipped with two instances, one for `Ixed` and one for non-`Ixed` types.  The type class is parametrized in both a data kind `Bool` for the presence of `Ixed` and the underlying type, like so:

```
class OpVal' (hasixed :: Bool) a where
  getOp :: Get (Op a)
```

and the two instances are selected by the `hasixed` type, which specifies the capabilities of `a`:

```
instance (Serialize a) => OpVal' False a where
  getOp = do
    i <- getWord8
    case i of
      1 -> Update <$> get
      _ -> error "instance Serialize (Op a) - corrupt data"
instance (Ixed a, Serialize (Index a), Serialize a) => OpVal' True a where
  getOp = do
    i <- getWord8
    case i of
      1 -> Update <$> get
      2 -> Reorder <$> get
      _ -> error "instance Serialize (Op a) - corrupt data"
```

To select the proper instance for a type, we define a type family:

```
type family HasIxed a :: Bool
```

which specifies whether or not a type `a` has `Ixed a`.  Then, we can use another type family to select the correct `OpVal'` instance based on `HasIxed`:

```
type family OpVal a where
  OpVal a = OpVal' (HasIxed a) a
```

Finally, we can define our `Serialize (Op a)` instance:

```
instance OpVal a => Serialize (Op a) where
  put (Update a) = putWord8 1 >> put a
  put (Reorder ks) = putWord8 2 >> put ks
  get = getOp @(HasIxed a)
```

With this in place, you can add types `a` to the open `HasIxed` type family:

```
type instance HasIxed Int = False
type instance HasIxed [Int] = True
```

and it all just kind of works:

```
instance OpVal a => Serialize (Op a) where
  put (Update a) = putWord8 1 >> put a
  put (Reorder ks) = putWord8 2 >> put ks
  get = getOp @(HasIxed a)

data BigThing a b = BigThing (Op a) (Op b) deriving (Generic)
instance (OpVal a, OpVal b) => Serialize (BigThing a b)

main = do
  let s = runPut $ put (BigThing (Update (5 :: Int)) (Reorder @[Int] [1,2,3]))
      Right (BigThing (Update x) (Reorder xs)) = runGet (get :: Get (BigThing Int [Int])) s
  print (x, xs)
```

The full example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}

import GHC.Generics (Generic)
import Control.Lens (Index, Ixed)
import Data.Serialize

data Op a where
  Update :: Serialize a => a -> Op a
  Reorder :: (Ixed a, Serialize (Index a)) => [Index a] -> Op a

class OpVal' (hasixed :: Bool) a where
  getOp :: Get (Op a)
instance (Serialize a) => OpVal' False a where
  getOp = do
    i <- getWord8
    case i of
      1 -> Update <$> get
      _ -> error "instance Serialize (Op a) - corrupt data"
instance (Ixed a, Serialize (Index a), Serialize a) => OpVal' True a where
  getOp = do
    i <- getWord8
    case i of
      1 -> Update <$> get
      2 -> Reorder <$> get
      _ -> error "instance Serialize (Op a) - corrupt data"

type family HasIxed a :: Bool
type instance HasIxed Int = False
type instance HasIxed [Int] = True

type family OpVal a where
  OpVal a = OpVal' (HasIxed a) a

instance OpVal a => Serialize (Op a) where
  put (Update a) = putWord8 1 >> put a
  put (Reorder ks) = putWord8 2 >> put ks
  get = getOp @(HasIxed a)

data BigThing a b = BigThing (Op a) (Op b) deriving (Generic)
instance (OpVal a, OpVal b) => Serialize (BigThing a b)

main = do
  let s = runPut $ put (BigThing (Update (5 :: Int)) (Reorder @[Int] [1,2,3]))
      Right (BigThing (Update x) (Reorder xs)) = runGet (get :: Get (BigThing Int [Int])) s
  print (x, xs)
```